# Google Cloud Messaging for Android Backend

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I have made an application which receives push notifications. The notification is sent and received when i send a request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send on my computer using this java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String value = "Kent Arne Bjerke har blitt med på din event";

    String url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    con.setRequestProperty("Sender", "id=xxxxxxxxxx");

    String urlParameters = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&registration_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

After testing this code locally on my computer, I wanted to implement the code on my google app engine server. I copyed the code and called it from a google app engine endpoint method. I then got this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Conne     ction cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection"
 }
}
```

If I understand it correctly I am not allowed to call https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send with this method.

I am looking for a good way to call Google Cloud Messaging for Android and send push notifications from my server and not the client. I have to send push notifications to multiple receivers, so it has to happend async.

Comment: I found a solution by using this code to send push notifications from the backend server:

    Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);
        Message msg = new Message.Builder().addData("message", message).build();
        
            Result result = sender.send(msg, "sender_id", 5);

Comment: Please you can give it as an answer if it worked for you and mark as answered.